# past simple in this case

Tags: past-tense

I was supposed to exchange houses, everything was planned when yesterday, I received an email saying that it was not possible to do it anymore .I answered "you should have emailed me as soon as you **knew/ have known** it

I think past simple is the best because I have known it since  yesterday so it belongs to the past

Answer (score 1):

> As soon as you have known

is incorrect, either

> as soon as you knew

or

> as soon as you had known

would be appropriate since you are talking about the past.